# Avraham was one of the builders of the Tower of Bavel?

Tags: abraham, parashat-noach, tower-of-babel

[Ibn Ezra to Gen. 11:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.11.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.11.1.1&lang2=bi) says that "Avraham was amongst the builders of the Tower."  "Hu haya Avraham mibonei hamigdal."  Does Ibn Ezra mean that Avraham Avinu was actually one of the builders of the Tower, and if so, does anyone comment on this fact, given that it is strange that Avraham was a tzaddik and the building of the Tower was a great sin, so why would Avraham have taken part in it?

Comment: Abraham is not on the list of people who never sinned

Comment: IIRC, Ibn Ezra holds that building the tower was not a sin - someone can feel free to find the quote and post as an answer, I'm not at my computer now.

Comment: @DoubleAA seems unnecessary to add sins to Avraham for no reason.

Comment: אברהם, שעל פי המדרש היה בן דורו של נמרוד,
מחליט להצטרף לבוני המגדל, כפי שאומר רבי
אברהם אבן עזרא: "אברהם מבוני המגדל היה".
אברהם אבינו, שגם היה אידיאליסט שרצה לתקן
את העולם, מנסה תחילה את דרכו של נמרוד.
אולם עד מהרה הוא מבין את גודל הטעות ומגיע
למסקנה אחרת לגמרי – שמצבו של העולם
גרוע מפני ששכחו את מי שברא את העולם.
האסטרטגיה שנוקט אברהם היא למרוד במורד
כדי להשיב את מלכות ה', ומתוך כך לפתור את
בעיות העולם. https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/pdf/pdf397/loro49.pdf

Comment: @DoubleAA What is your source for "Abraham is not on the list of people who never sinned"

Comment: The Rambam says Avraham was an idol worshipper in the beginning of his life. So there is no reason to think he did not participate in the building of the Tower.

Comment: @Efraym [Bava Basra 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.17a.6)

Comment: @iceoi83 it's a machlokes how old he was when be discovered Hashem. [The Rambam says 40](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah,_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.1.3).

Comment: This would seemingly contradict the view of the midrash as brought in Yalkut Shimoni 62 https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.62.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en which writes that when the people started building migdal bavel, Avraham mocked and cursed them - עמד אברהם והלעיג בם וקללם בשם אלקיו

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your question is that the Ibn Ezra follows has the same opinion as the [Rambam](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.1.3?lang=bi&with=Kessef%20Mishneh&lang2=he) who writes that Avraham Avinu was 40 when he recognized Hashem, but before that he worshipped idols.

> כֵּיוָן שֶׁנִּגְמַל אֵיתָן זֶה הִתְחִיל לְשׁוֹטֵט בְּדַעְתּוֹ וְהוּא קָטָן וְהִתְחִיל לַחֲשֹׁב בַּיּוֹם וּבַלַּיְלָה וְהָיָה תָּמֵהַּ הֵיאַךְ אֶפְשָׁר שֶׁיִּהְיֶה הַגַּלְגַּל הַזֶּה נוֹהֵג תָּמִיד וְלֹא יִהְיֶה לוֹ מַנְהִיג וּמִי יְסַבֵּב אוֹתוֹ. כִּי אִי אֶפְשָׁר שֶׁיְּסַבֵּב אֶת עַצְמוֹ. וְלֹא הָיָה לוֹ מְלַמֵּד וְלֹא מוֹדִיעַ דָּבָר אֶלָּא מֻשְׁקָע בְּאוּר כַּשְׂדִּים בֵּין עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים הַטִּפְּשִׁים וְאָבִיו וְאִמּוֹ וְכָל הָעָם עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים **וְהוּא עוֹבֵד עִמָּהֶם** וְלִבּוֹ מְשׁוֹטֵט וּמֵבִין עַד שֶׁהִשִּׂיג דֶּרֶךְ הָאֱמֶת וְהֵבִין קַו הַצֶּדֶק מִתְּבוּנָתוֹ הַנְּכוֹנָה. וְיָדַע שֶׁיֵּשׁ שָׁם אֱלוֹהַּ אֶחָד וְהוּא מַנְהִיג הַגַּלְגַּל וְהוּא בָּרָא הַכּל וְאֵין בְּכָל הַנִּמְצָא אֱלוֹהַּ חוּץ מִמֶּנּוּ. וְיָדַע שֶׁכָּל הָעוֹלָם טוֹעִים וְדָבָר שֶׁגָּרַם לָהֶם לִטְעוֹת זֶה שֶׁעוֹבְדִים אֶת הַכּוֹכָבִים וְאֶת הַצּוּרוֹת עַד שֶׁאָבַד הָאֱמֶת מִדַּעְתָּם. **וּבֶן אַרְבָּעִים שָׁנָה הִכִּיר אַבְרָהָם אֶת בּוֹרְאוֹ.**
> As soon as this giant was weaned he commenced to busy his mind, in his infancy he commenced to think by day and by night, and would encounter this enigma: How is it possible that this planet should continuously be in motion and have no leader—and who, indeed, causes it to revolve, it being impossible that it should revolve itself? Moreover, he neither had a teacher nor one to impart aught to him, for he was sunk in Ur of the Chaldeans among the foolish worshipers of stars, and his father, and his mother, like all the people, worshiped stars, **and he, although following them in their worship**, busies his heart and reflects until he attains the path of truth, and, by his correct thinking, he understood when he finally saw the line of righteousness. He knew that there is One God; He leads the planet; He created everything; and in all that is there is no god save He. He knew that the whole world was in error, and that the thing which caused them to err was, that their worshiping the stars and the images brought about the loss of the truth from their consciousness. **And, when Abraham was forty years old he recognized his Creator.**

The [Ohr Sameach](https://www.sefaria.org/Ohr_Sameach_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.1.3?lang=bi&p2=Bereishit_Rabbah.39.8&lang2=he) identifies the source of the Rambam as the Medrash Rabbah which says

> לךָ טַל יַלְדוּתֶיךָ, לְפִי שֶׁהָיָה אָבִינוּ אַבְרָהָם מִתְפַּחֵד וְאוֹמֵר תֹּאמַר שֶׁיֵּשׁ בְּיָדִי עָוֹן שֶׁהָיִיתִי עוֹבֵד עֲבוֹדָה זָרָה כָּל הַשָּׁנִים הַלָּלוּ, אָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְךָ טַל יַלְדוּתֶךָ מַה טַּל זֶה פּוֹרֵחַ, אַף עֲוֹנוֹתֶיךָ פּוֹרְחִים

As to how that fits in with the Gemara that says Avraham Avinu recognized Hashem at three, the Kesef Mishneh resolves the question by saying that at three Avraham Avinu began the intellectual process that ultimately lead to his recognizing Hashem (described in the beginning of the Rambam) but did not succeed until he reached the age of 40.

The same thing is said by the [Meiri](https://mishna.alhatorah.org/Full/Avot/0#e1n6) in his introduction to Avos:

> עד שהגיע הזמן לאברהם אבינו ע״ה שנולד אחר הזמן הנז׳ קצ״ב שנים הוקדש מרחם ומלידה ומבטן ומהריון מבית אסורים יצא למלוך ומאור כשדים ניצול להציל עם עצום עושה דברו לכפר על עם ה׳ ולהשיב את נדחו בתחילת למודו נגלה טוב מזגו ונתפרסם יושר הכנתו עד שכל יודעיו יקוו לו הבינו לאחריתו **והוא אצלי אומרם ז״ל עליו נדרים ל״ב א׳ ובב״ר פ״ל ופס״ד בן שלש שנים הכיר אברהם את בוראו רומז על פרסום הכנתו והיות כל העולם מכירים אחדותו הצליח בלימודו והשיג עד תכלית מה שאפשר לפי טבעו והיה אז אברהם אע״ה בן ארבעים שנה והוא אומרם ז״ל במקום אחר בן ארבעים שנה הכיר אברהם את בוראו** וכשראה את עצמו שלם עם ראותו קלקול בני דורו לבשתהו רוח ה׳ וקנא בחכמתו בשם ה׳ וקבץ אלפים ורבבות לעבוד את ה׳ וליחד את שמו בעולם לבער אלילים מן הארץ והיה זה בשנת נ״ב ללידתו והוא שנת יציאתו מחרן

Comment: How old was Avraham when the tower was built? If he was older than forty this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: N.T. and @robev according to the footnote on the English translation on the Ibn Ezra in Sefaria, Avraham was 48 during the time of the Tower.

Comment: @Harel13 He was 48 at the time of the dispersion, which is when Hashem *stopped* construction on the tower. However, considering the tower was a massive project, it probably went on for many years. In fact, in school we were taught that it took an entire year to place each brick in the tower. Not sure what the actual source is.

Comment: @N.T. A year to place a brick? Sounds very far from p'shat. I suppose the question would be how long a ziggurat or ziggurat-like structure took to build.

Comment: @Harel13 I pictured it as bricks being massive in size. But really I don't know.